# Calculate time difference over the first and the last table row

Tags: postgresql

Within postgresql, I'm trying to write a query that calculates the time difference between a time stamp of the first row and a time stamp of the last row:

```
(select public."ImportLogs"."DateTimeStamp" as migration_start from public."ImportLogs" order by public."ImportLogs"."DateTimeStamp" asc limit 1)
union
(select public."ImportLogs"."DateTimeStamp" as migration_end from public."ImportLogs" order by public."ImportLogs"."DateTimeStamp" desc limit 1);
```

I tried to get the time difference between `migration_start` and `migration_end`, but I couldn't get it to work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can substract `min(DateTimeStamp)` from the max(DateTimeStamp)` and cast the difference as time.

> ```
> select 
>   cast(
>      max(DateTimeStamp) 
>    - min(DateTimeStamp)
>      as time) TimeDiffernce 
> from ImportLogs
> ```
>
> ```
> | timediffernce |
> | :------------ |
> | 00:00:10      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a51a621713d9f98420525ab682cef93f)*

Comment: Great solution, thanks!